# Telegram Group Members List From ID

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

Using the *group_ID* if a bot is member in the corresponding group and can observe messages, is there a way to retrieve the members list with a sort of "one shot" query?

I see that there is not this in **Telegram Bot API**, but as member with my device app i can observ the list of group members.

So is there a way to do the same as bot that is member in a group and knowing the *group_ID*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current api doesn't support getting member list for groups.

A small workaround is to start building the list from all messages received (and also new participant updates). Of course it won't be completely exact, but may help.

Regards

Comment: Thanks i did this approach and i am curios about it.